# How does folding text render their Markdown?

Tags: javascript, css, markdown, text-editor

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas of how to go about making something similar to folding text (http://www.foldingtext.com/).

I have found this example on codemirror which is close to what they achieve: http://codemirror.net/demo/variableheight.html

However, I am looking for how they hide the bold tags around bold words when not on the current word. I can understand the dimming of the ### tags for headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is the property contentEditable.
With that you can make a div editable, this make possible to insert html tags into this div just by type.

```
<div id="editableDiv" contentEditable=true>
    testing la la la testing la la la testing la la la 
    lulululu <span style="background-color:blue;">formated Text</span> <br>
    lulululu <span style="background-color:red;">Formated Text</span>
</div>
```

Now, if you want to apply an style while you type, you need to monit the keypress (or something) and parse the content to html elements, this is a hard task, so I which you luck.